# NoClassDefFoundError: L => "L" added to import path by 'system' creates error

Tags: java, glassfish, netbeans-7

All,

I have had this now a couple of times..I create a new Java Enterprise Web Application on Netbeans, add Primefaces 4, Spring on glassfish running MySql

I have some reference tool classes in my ejb project and I added classes through the Finder/Explorer on Mac. Clean & build works all fine but when I want to deploy I get the error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/utils/sql/SqlUtils;

This is a class I import correctly everywhere as org/utils/sql/SqlUtils but for some reason it adds a "L" in front and then obviously cant find it. I had found previously that removing the class and disabling imports that it simply complains about any other file.

In a previous project I had some automatically created entity classes and the error occurred when I deleted them, even though they had nothing todo with the import related error. When I put the entity classes back then also the error disappeared.

If anybody could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you paste stacktrace that would be easier. I am basically looking if there is a ClassNotFoundException or ExceptionInitializationError in it.

Comment: `Lorg/utils/sql/SqlUtils` is the canonical name used by the JVM for the Java class `org.utils.sql.SqlUtils`. The error is more likely due to a missing library than to an added L.

Answer (score 2):

What you see is the internal name of class `org.utils.sql.SqlUtils`.

For an explanation, see [4.3 Descriptors and Signatures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3) in the Java Virtual Machine specification. The prefix `L` means that the type is a class, as you can see there.

As Darkhogg mentioned in a comment, the problem most likely happens because you're missing a library in your classpath that contains the class `org.utils.sql.SqlUtils`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All..that was certainly helpful in understanding the "L". Also I managed to fix up some of the dependencies but at the end it reverted back to its original error. This I now 'fixed' by re-inserting the entity classes into the ejb project. I dont use them and they are useless baggage and I dont understand why I cant run the application without it...

in any case FYI the stack without my 'fix' above is:

> INFO:   SEC1002: Security Manager is OFF.
>   INFO:   SEC1010: Entering Security Startup Service INFO:   SEC1143:
>   Loading policy provider
>   com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper. INFO:   SEC1011:
>   Security Service(s) Started Successfully INFO:
>   this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.web.glue, null) returned
>   OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.web.glue [350]], State =
>   [READY] INFO:
>   this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.web.javax.servlet.jsp, null) returned
>   OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.web.javax.servlet.jsp [209]],
>   State = [READY] INFO:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on
>   host/port 0.0.0.0:8080 INFO:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2
>   on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181 INFO:   Created HTTP listener admin-listener
>   on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848 INFO:   Created virtual server server INFO: 
>   Created virtual server __asadmin INFO:   Setting JAAS app name
>   glassfish-web INFO:   Virtual server server loaded default web module 
>   INFO:   WELD-000900 2.0.0 (SP1) SEVERE:   Exception while invoking
>   class org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer load method
>   org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-001202 Error
>   parsing
>   file:/Users/drtobiaswahl/NetBeansProjects/MovieWahl/dist/gfdeploy/MovieWahl/MovieWahl-war_war/WEB-INF/beans.xml
>     at org.jboss.weld.xml.BeansXmlParser.parse(BeansXmlParser.java:114)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.parse(WeldBootstrap.java:676)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.parseBeansXML(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:747)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.populate(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:371)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:147)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.RootBeanDeploymentArchive.createModuleBda(RootBeanDeploymentArchive.java:94)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.RootBeanDeploymentArchive.(RootBeanDeploymentArchive.java:87)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.RootBeanDeploymentArchive.(RootBeanDeploymentArchive.java:75)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.DeploymentImpl.createModuleBda(DeploymentImpl.java:711)
>     at org.glassfish.weld.DeploymentImpl.(DeploymentImpl.java:131)
>     at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.load(WeldDeployer.java:464)  at
>   org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.load(WeldDeployer.java:100)   at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)  at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 6; The
>   processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1388)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPIData(XMLScanner.java:675)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanPIData(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1024)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPI(XMLScanner.java:643)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:912)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:846)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:775)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:628)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:332)
>     at org.jboss.weld.xml.BeansXmlParser.parse(BeansXmlParser.java:108)
>     ... 47 more
>
> SEVERE:   Exception during lifecycle processing
>   org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-001202 Error
>   parsing
>   file:/Users/drtobiaswahl/NetBeansProjects/MovieWahl/dist/gfdeploy/MovieWahl/MovieWahl-war_war/WEB-INF/beans.xml
>     at org.jboss.weld.xml.BeansXmlParser.parse(BeansXmlParser.java:114)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.parse(WeldBootstrap.java:676)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.parseBeansXML(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:747)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.populate(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:371)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:147)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.RootBeanDeploymentArchive.createModuleBda(RootBeanDeploymentArchive.java:94)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.RootBeanDeploymentArchive.(RootBeanDeploymentArchive.java:87)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.RootBeanDeploymentArchive.(RootBeanDeploymentArchive.java:75)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.DeploymentImpl.createModuleBda(DeploymentImpl.java:711)
>     at org.glassfish.weld.DeploymentImpl.(DeploymentImpl.java:131)
>     at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.load(WeldDeployer.java:464)  at
>   org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.load(WeldDeployer.java:100)   at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)  at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 6; The
>   processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1388)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPIData(XMLScanner.java:675)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanPIData(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1024)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPI(XMLScanner.java:643)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:912)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:846)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:775)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:628)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:332)
>     at org.jboss.weld.xml.BeansXmlParser.parse(BeansXmlParser.java:108)
>     ... 47 more
>
> SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app SEVERE:   Exception while
>   loading the app : WELD-001202 Error parsing
>   file:/Users/drtobiaswahl/NetBeansProjects/MovieWahl/dist/gfdeploy/MovieWahl/MovieWahl-war_war/WEB-INF/beans.xml
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 6; The
>   processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1388)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPIData(XMLScanner.java:675)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanPIData(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1024)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPI(XMLScanner.java:643)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:912)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:846)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:775)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:628)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:332)
>     at org.jboss.weld.xml.BeansXmlParser.parse(BeansXmlParser.java:108)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.parse(WeldBootstrap.java:676)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.parseBeansXML(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:747)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.populate(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:371)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:147)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.RootBeanDeploymentArchive.createModuleBda(RootBeanDeploymentArchive.java:94)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.RootBeanDeploymentArchive.(RootBeanDeploymentArchive.java:87)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.RootBeanDeploymentArchive.(RootBeanDeploymentArchive.java:75)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.DeploymentImpl.createModuleBda(DeploymentImpl.java:711)
>     at org.glassfish.weld.DeploymentImpl.(DeploymentImpl.java:131)
>     at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.load(WeldDeployer.java:464)  at
>   org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.load(WeldDeployer.java:100)   at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)  at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
>
> SEVERE:   Exception(s) thrown during observer of BeforeShutdown
>   SEVERE:   java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:63)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeShutdownImpl.fire(BeforeShutdownImpl.java:48)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeShutdownImpl.fire(BeforeShutdownImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.shutdown(WeldBootstrap.java:642)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.doBootstrapShutdown(WeldDeployer.java:309)
>     at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:276)     at
>   org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl$1.run(EventsImpl.java:123)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
>
> WARNING:   AS-CDI-036